# Are the elements $x_I$ all distinct?

Tags: real-analysis, set-theory

Given a subset $I \subseteq \mathbb N$ consider the element $x_I \in (0,2)$ defined by $x_I = \sum\limits_{i \in I} \frac {1} {i!}.$ Are $x_I$'s all distinct for distinct subsets $I \subseteq \mathbb N\ $? If not, can we at least conclude that the set of all $I \subseteq \mathbb N$ such that $x_I$'s are all distinct is an uncountable set?

I can't conclude any of these. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why is $x_I \in (1, 2)$? If $I=\{2\}$ for example $x_I = 0.5 < 1$.

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis$:$ I actually meant $(0,2).$ Fixed it. Thanks for pointing out the error. Although that's not a determining factor. Do you have any idea about how one should proceed to prove (or disprove) such things?

Comment: Uniqueness can be approached using ideas from "factorial base" expressions, see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system

Comment: I just want to point out that "the set of all $I \subseteq \mathbb N$
 such that $x_I$'s are all distinct" is not a meaningfully defined set.  You could ask, however, if there is *some* uncountable set of $I$'s for which the $x_I$'s are distinct - I suspect that is what you were going for perhaps?  In that case, since all the $x_I$'s are distinct anyway (per my answer below), and the power set of $\mathbb N$ is uncountable, the answer would be "yes".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they are all distinct.

First observe that for $n\geq 1$,

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{n!} \geq \frac{1}{n!}\cdot \frac{1}{n} =
\frac{1}{n!}\cdot \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^j
>
\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}\text{.}
\end{align*}

Now, suppose $I\neq J$ are subsets of $\mathbb N$, with $n$ the first element of $\mathbb N$ for which the sets differ, i.e. WLOG $n$ is in $I$ but not $J$.  Then the preceding inequality shows that $x_I>x_J$.

Comment: Very nice answer.

Comment: Thanks, glad to help!